# How to prevent auto scroll down after printing a list in flutter

Tags: android, database, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am a newbie to flutter. So recently I was working with ListView Builders. So I printed my whole list of data in the screen but I want my screen focus to stay at the top instead of going at the bottom after finishing printing the list.

Basically I just want to stay at the top of the screen.

Here is my code for listView.builder

```
return ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  reverse: true,
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return SingleChildScrollView(
                        child: Container(
                            height: null,
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                horizontal: 20, vertical: 10),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius:
                                    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
                                color: Colors.white,
                                boxShadow: [
                                  BoxShadow(
                                      color: Colors.black.withAlpha(100),
                                      blurRadius: 10.0),
                                ]),
                            child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                    horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 10),
                                child: Column(
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                        CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                            0.0, 0.0, 10.0, 0.0),
                                        child: Text(
                                          snapshot.data[index].data()["date"],
                                          style: const TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 16,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                            0.0, 0.0, 10.0, 0.0),
                                        child: Text(
                                          snapshot.data[index].data()["notice"],
                                          style: const TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 19.0,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                            5.0, 10.0, 5.0, 10.0),
                                        child: Text(
                                          snapshot.data[index].data()["actual"],
                                          style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                                              fontSize: 15.5,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ]))));
                  });
```

I hope you understood my question.
Thank you!

Comment: Try reversing the list order through the sort method instead of setting reverse: true in the listview.  Listview will always scroll to the first item, which would be at the bottom, if reverse is set to true.

Comment: I just simply want to be at the top without changing the order.
I want my new data values at the top not at the bottom thats why.
So, is there any other option?

Comment: That's why I recommend changing the order of the List.  You change the List order so the most recent data is at the beginning of the list.  This will not affect the actual data, just the list of the incoming data.  The reverse property will always put the first item at the bottom, hence the "reverse" keyword.

Comment: The only other way I can think of preventing this is to set physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), but it might still set the scroll to the bottom.

Comment: Hmm maybe you could try adding an image ? I can't undestand what are you trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

OK Finally I did it. Thanks to @scottgodfrey from him i got the idea of making the reverse false and after that i updated the index with the length of the document-1 so by this I was able to print the data in a reversed manner without printing it one by one and without using reverse which used to take my screen to the bottom!